# How can I modify/extend a global TWIG variable?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, yaml

I know you can set global variables in TWIG this way :

```
# config.yml
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    cache : false
    globals :
        server : 127.0.0.1
```

Now what I want is to create a custom variable `server` that uses the preexistent global variable `app.request.host`. I can reference that variable in a TWIG template, but how can I do that in a YML file ?

**In one sentence** : I want to create a global TWIG variable from another one.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go with a parameter.
Just put it in you parameters.yml

```
server: 127.0.0.1
```

after that you can refer to it in yml files like this:

```
"%server%"
```

add it to globals like this:

```
twig:
    globals:
        server: '%server%'
```

if you need it in controller, then use this approach:

```
$this->getParameter("server")
```

Comment: Because that's not what I want. I want to use the preexisting `app.request.host` variable which automatically sets itself to the domain where the code is executed. In your example, I'd have to update `parameters.yml` each time I change the domain, which I dont want to do. By the way, where are these  framework variables defined ? Maybe I can simply modify them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. But you can also inject a service as a global twig variable like this server: "@some_service". This service can return any value including another global twig variable. Just inject twig to that service and use this to get them $twig->getGlobals().